# Font color not changing when choosing different theme in aptana studio 3.6 for HTML

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana

I found a post where font color was not changing for Aptana Studio 3.6 for Python and the user was able to use the Color Theme Plugin to get it working. I have the Color Theme plugin however, HTML is always a dark red for tags, light red for attributes, blue for properties, and black for values. Please advise.

[image: Aptana Screenshot]

Comment: Hello jth, did you get the font color to working?